# Display a tooltip with percent of total number of observations on ggplot histogram?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, ggplotly

I have a histogram and I'd like the tooltip to show the percent of observations in that bin.

Here's a simple (reproducible) histogram:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
 
hist <- iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 20)
 
hist %>%
  ggplotly(
    # This gives hoverover the count and the variable, but I'd like it
    # to also have the percent of total observations contained in that bin
    tooltip=c("count", "Sepal.Length")
  )
```

Along with "count" and "Sepal.Length", I'd like to also show the percent of the total number of observations in the tooltip.

For example, the left-most bin (which contains 4 observations), should have a value of 2.7% (4/150)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try using `text` argument in `ggplot` and set to the count divided by the sum of all counts. Using `sprintf` you can get the format desired. In your `tooltip` reference `text`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

hist <- iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, 
             text = sprintf("Percent: %0.1f", ..count../sum(..count..) * 100))) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 20)

hist %>%
  ggplotly(
    tooltip=c("count", "text", "Sepal.Length")
  )
```

Comment: This is a great answer. Not only is it functional, but also very elegant.